# What is the max number of permissions I can assign to a custom policy on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

Say an organization has custom IAM policies from which roles are assigned any number of policies. ***Is there a max number of permissions per custom policy that can be assigned?*** Or is the policy size limited by char count?

As far as documentation, I'm not certain if there is a threshold, or if the max value is based on bytes, or n characters:

> **[Q: How many policies can I attach to an IAM role?](https://aws.amazon.com/iam/faqs/)**
> For inline policies: You can add as many inline policies as you want to a user, role, or group, but the total aggregate policy size (the sum size of all inline policies) per entity cannot exceed the following limits:
>
> - User policy size cannot exceed 2,048 characters.
> - Role policy size cannot exceed 10,240 characters.
> - Group policy size cannot exceed 5,120 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs you reference seem fairly straightforward; according to what you quote the limit is on the sum of characters in all the inline policies attached to the user / role / group